# Почему текст после формы переносится на следующую строку?

Tags: php, html, вёрстка

В коде после формы НЕТ ни одного `<br>`. Только `php` код, который присваивает переменные. Место справа от формы много, но браузер переносит на следующую строку. Мне это не нужно. Подскажите пожалуйста что я должен проверить? После формы текст "Текущие данные" идет с новой строки

```
<form action='newstudents.php' method='POST'>
    <select name="choosetable">
    <?php 
    for ($i=0; $i <count($tbl_array) ; $i++) { 
       $table[0]=$tbl_array[$i];  # code...

    ?>
<option value="<?php echo $table[0];?>"><?php echo $table[0];?></option>

<?};?>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Выбрать дату">
</form>

<?

if (!isset($_POST['choosetable'])) {
    if (empty ($_SESSION['choose_table'])) {
    $_SESSION['choose_table']=$_SESSION['choose_table_name']=$tbl_array[0]; 
}} else {
   $_SESSION['choose_table']=$_SESSION['choose_table_name']=$_POST['choosetable'];
};
?>


<b><font face="Arial" color="#f38630"><?
if ($_SESSION['choose_table']==$tbl_array[0]) {
    echo "Текущие данные";# code...
} else {
echo "Данные по соcтоянию на " . $choose_table_name;};
?></font></b>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что `form` блочный элемент (по-умолчанию `display: block`):

```css
form {
  border:1px solid #777;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
  
  <form>
    Форма
    
    <input type="text" name="x" id="x">
  </form>
  
  <span>Текст после формы</span>
```

Для того, чтобы текст шел рядом с формой можно задать форме `display: inline-block`:

```css
form {
  border:1px solid #777;
  padding: 10px;
  
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
  <form>
    Форма
    
    <input type="text" name="x" id="x">
  </form>
  
  <span>Текст после формы</span>
```

Comment: А где этот атрибут display: inline-block должен быть задан? Это похоже на CSS.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Разобрался